# How do I create a deb package with basic dependencies?

Tags: java, ubuntu, debian, packaging, debian-based

Hi so I am trying to create a deb package for a web application written in Java (it uses Apache Tomcat). My eventual goal is to start a repository that people can add to `apt-get` the software, but

1. How do I make it so that the package knows to look for dependencies like tomcat, sun-java6-bin, and ant?
2. How do I write an installer script to place the files and folders in the right place?

Comment: Try asking this in the Ubuntu Development & Programming forum - http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=310

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great tutorial at http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/

Comment: I'm using it right now but do you know if ubuntu is in any way different, or are all debian packages compatible with ubuntu?

Comment: Okay I'm at a dead end, it keeps talking about make files and install files that I have no clue about. my software doesn't have any of that (it's a platform-independent web app whose only dependency is really JRE & tomcat). I know how to make it look for dependencies now, that's easy, but the whole install part is beyond me...help?

Comment: I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8477514/1298153) quite useful, as it had a deeper link to the bits of the tutorial that define the dependencies.