# How to install dependencies while creating a .deb installer?

Tags: installation, controls, deb, build-dependencies, post-install

I have created a `deb` package say `abc.deb`. Now there are few dependencies like `python-dev, python-mysql` etc., which are needed to be installed as a part of deb installation itself.

(i.e. when user runs `dpkg -i abc.deb`, the dependencies should also get installed automatically).

I am using a `control` file which contains few parameters like `preinst, postinst` etc. I tried to add `Depends` to the control file, but I guess, `Depends` only stops package installation if dependencies mentioned are not present. How could I install the dependencies as a part of deb package installation itself? I am looking for a solution that will work on `Ubuntu 12.04`.

P.S. When I try to install dependencies in my `postinst` script as

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev -y
```

I gives me an error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) 
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this through `dpkg`; that's what `apt-get` is for. If you specify the dependencies properly in your `.deb` control files, then install with `apt-get`, it will install them automatically for you. You shouldn't be trying to call the higher-level tool from the lower-level one. By that time, it's too late.

Comment: Hi @BRPocock, thanks a lot for your reply. What if I do not wish to install the dependencies, but would want to let the user know what error is and then revert the installed packages (i.e. something effective to `dpkg -r abc.deb` so that my apt-get will remain clean)?

Comment: Just list them as dependencies. `dpkg` will give an informative error; `apt-get` will offer to install them. The user decides whether to do so.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg` can only install single packages.

You should declare all your package's dependencies in the `Depends` field of the control file.

If your user then installs the package with `dpkg -i package.deb`, they will get a message that dependencies are missing.  The user can then invoke `apt-get -f install` to fix missing dependencies from the package repository (this assumes that your dependencies actually *are* in the official repositories).

An alternative is to use a tool such as `gdebi` to install your package; `gdebi` knows how to fetch missing dependencies, making the `apt-get -f install` step unnecessary.

My advice is to ship your `package.deb` file (with proper dependency declaration) to your users, and advise them to install it with `gdebi`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I achieved this is by using the `preinst` script. This script executes before that package will be unpacked from its Debian archive (".deb") file.

I checked for the dependencies in `preinst` script and then exited with an error if dependencies were not found. Following sample sh code shows how to check and install dependencies if unavailable :

```
  dpkg -s "python-pip" >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
    echo "python-pip is installed."
    echo
  } || {
    echo "ERROR: python-pip is not installed."
    //you may install python-pip here if you wish
  }
```

Then this script is provided to `Preinst:` parameter of control file.

Comment: This is bad advice.  "preinst" hooks are not supposed to install other packages.  The package needs to declare `Depends:`.